# How can I draw gizmos and move the drawn gizmos when moving the transform in the editor in scene view?

Tags: unity, unityscript

```
public void OnDrawGizmos() {
        if(_thisT == null) _thisT = transform;
            if(!Application.isPlaying && _posBuffer != _thisT.position+_startPosOffset){
                _posBuffer = _thisT.position+_startPosOffset;

            }
            if(_positionSphereDepth == -1){
                    _positionSphereDepth = _positionSphere;
                }   
                if(_spawnSphereDepth == -1){
                    _spawnSphereDepth = _spawnSphere;
                }
            Gizmos.color = Color.blue;
            Gizmos.DrawWireCube (_posBuffer, new Vector3(_spawnSphere*2, _spawnSphereHeight*2 ,_spawnSphereDepth*2));
            Gizmos.color = Color.cyan;
            Gizmos.DrawWireCube (_thisT.position, new Vector3((_positionSphere*2)+_spawnSphere*2, (_positionSphereHeight*2)+_spawnSphereHeight*2 ,(_positionSphereDepth*2)+_spawnSphereDepth*2));
        }
```

_posBuffer is Vector3
_spawnSphereDepth is float

The problem is that it's drawing the cube in the center of the scene view window and when I'm changing the transform position the cube Gizmo is not moving.

Is there a way to draw the DrawWireCube so it will be position around the transform and when moving the transform that the gizmos draws will move with it too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the vector given is a world position. If you want a gizmo to be drawn with the player, you must add that transform's position:

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Color color;
    public Vector3 gizmoPosition;
    public float radius;

    void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = color;
        Vector3 newPosition = transform.position + gizmoPosition;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(newPosition, radius);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.